# How to assign a different number of elements to different rows in a 3D numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I am trying to use an array to index another array.  The goal is to put the value (val) in the first row(2nd axis) a different number of time(num). I am not very good at explaining this, but the result of the example shows what I am looking for. I think I am very close.

I get this error:

> TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

```
import numpy as np 

# dataset
data = np.zeros((3, 4, 5))
val = np.array([6, 7, 8])
num = np.array([2, 4, 3])

# Do something like this, using an index, not a loop
data[:, 0][:, 0:num] = val

# This is the result I am hoping to get

[[[6. 6. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]

 [[7. 7. 7. 7. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]

 [[8. 8. 8. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]]
```

Comment: In the `0:num`, `num` has to be a scalar, a single value.  You give it a 3 element array.  You can't create multiple slices that way.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
ind = (np.repeat(range(3), num),
       np.zeros(num.sum(), dtype='int'),
       np.hstack([np.arange(i) for i in num]))
tVal = np.repeat(val, num)
data[ind] = tVal
```

Print *ind* and *tVal* to see the intermediate objects.

Details:

1. `ind` is a tuple of index arrays (for each dimension). The first
   array for the first dimension and so on. It is a "composite index"
   of elements to be set.
2. `tVal` contains values to be set in consecutive elements of *data*.
3. `data[ind] = tVal` performs the actual substitution (each value from *tVal*
   into the indicated element of *data*).

Read about each used *Numpy* method to get acquainted with other details
and background.

Comment: I am trying to vectorize this to make it run faster.  This was the fastest loop I found:

for i in range(len(num)):
    example[:, 0][i, 0:num[i]] = val[i]

print(example)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `data` is actually all zeros, you can do this very simply with `np.cumsum` using a technique I normally use for masking. The key is to set the beginning and end of a run using straightforward indexing, and then to sum between them.

```
data[:, 0, 0] = val   # Start the sum
data[np.arange(data.shape[0]), 0, num] = -val
data.cumsum(axis=-1, out=data)
```

If `num == data.shape[-1]` is ever `True`, you will need to filter the index first, to run the sum until the end:

```
mask = (num < data.shape[-1])
data[np.arange(data.shape[0])[mask], 0, num[mask]] = -val
```

If `data` is not all zeros, you can just as easily create a mask and use it in conjunction with `np.repeat`. You make the mask using the same technique of `np.cumsum` and the fact that `np.uint8` and `np.bool_` have the same itemsize:

```
mask = np.zeros_like(data, dtype=np.uint8)
mask[:, 0, 0] = 1   # Start the sum
m = (num < data.shape[-1])
mask[np.arange(data.shape[0])[m], 0, num[m]] = -1
mask.cumsum(axis=-1, out=mask)
mask = mask.view(bool)

data[mask] = np.repeat(val, num)
```

If you're only interested in the first row of each plane, you could likely operate on a view that only includes those rows to make the indexing simpler:

```
x = data[:, 0, :]
```